# nodejs Promise.all() not working after promise process

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I want to download images so I used Promise.

And my code snipped like that:

```
var download = function(uri, filename, callback) {
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body) {
    /* console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']); */

    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename + '.' + res.headers['content-type'].split('/')[1])).on('close', callback);
  });
};

var imagePaths = [];

for (const imageURL of imageURLs) {
  imagePaths.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let filename = __dirname + '/../../../downloads/' + naming(6)
    download(imageURL, filename, function(data, err) {
      console.log("download image successful")
    });
  }))
}

Promise.all(imagePaths).then(() => {
  console.log("11")
  console.log(imagePaths)
});
```

And my output like that:

```
download image successful
download image successful
download image successful
```

And,

```
Promise.all(imagePaths).then(() => {
        console.log("11")
        console.log(imagePaths)

    });
```

not working.

Why Im not getting imagePaths? How can I solve this?

Comment: You're not resolving your promise. You're just console.logging it.

Comment: Replace `console.log("download image successful")` with `resolve("download image successful")` or call `resolve()` separately

Comment: Thanks for answers. I replace with "resolve(imageURL)". But now, console.log(imagePaths) output like that: -----------------------


[
  Promise {
    'https://www.nevaevde.com/neva-nv10022-siyah-6li-buyuk-su-mesrubat-bardak-takimi-su-mesrubat-seti-icecek-seti-neva-1912-30-B.jpg'
  },
  Promise {
    'https://st2.myideasoft.com/idea/be/12/myassets/products/908/ince-bardak.jpg'
  },
  Promise {
    'https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/41/375/10689840480306.jpg'
  }
]-----------------------

Comment: Why output shows that "Promise"

Comment: Because `imagePaths` is an array of promises. What do you expect?

Comment: Expected output like that: ---------------

[ 
    'https://www.nevaevde.com/neva-nv10022-siyah-6li-buyuk-su-mesrubat-bardak-takimi-su-mesrubat-seti-icecek-seti-neva-1912-30-B.jpg',
    'https://st2.myideasoft.com/idea/be/12/myassets/products/908/ince-bardak.jpg',
    'https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/41/375/10689840480306.jpg'

]

Comment: Not even in your download function do you return the value `nevaevde.com/…` etc. If you look at your return value by doing `Promise.all(imagePaths).then(x => console.log(x)` you will get an array `["download image successful","download image successful","download image successful"...]`. That's what the resolve is for -- to return the value of the promise.

Comment: Note that if `imagePaths` is an array of string like you expect then `Promise.all()` will fail because it expects an array of promises.

Comment: If I were you I would rename the variable `imagePaths` to `downloadPromises` to avoid confusion

Comment: Promise.all(imagePaths).then((resolvedData) => {
        console.log("11")
        console.log(resolvedData)

    });